# From Voronoi diagram to skeleton

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry, voronoi

I guess this might be a simple question, but I was wondering:

Is it possible and how would you skeletonize a model having its [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) available?

Any ideas? Links?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but see http://ganacim.impa.br/gc/maxis/maxis.html.

Comment: With the 2D or 3D voronoi diagram?  Also, if you have a picture of desired input and output it would help understand what you're trying to achieve.  Doesn't have to be nice, ms paint would be great.. :)

Comment: Related: Here's a MATLAB function that calculates the Skeleton as a subgraph of the Voronoi diagram: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27543-skeletonization-using-voronoi

Answer (score 1):

There are interesting relationships between the *medial axis* and the *Voronoi diagram*, so a search for some papers will likely return interesting results. I think the paper [Approximating the Medial Axis from the Voronoi Diagram with a Convergence Guarantee](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~tamaldey/paper/medial.pdf) might be helpful.

A simple algorithm that I have seen to work with some polygonal shapes works like this:

- Create the Voronoi diagram
- Remove all half-edges so that only edges connecting two "finite" points remain
- Optionally prune edges that connect two points on the boundary of your shape
- The remaining graph is, for some cases, a pretty good approximation to the skeleton of your shape

You also might want to search for the *medial axis* as mentioned above. Keep in mind, though, that **all** these simple representations are very prone to noise in your data set.